# Почему не регулируется высота карусели по самому высокому элементу?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, карусель

Есть `owl carusel` в которой блоки разной высоты для чего, согласно документации, прописал в карусели инструкцию `autoHeight: true`. Но, высота карусели меняется на самый высокий элемент только тогда, когда элемент занимает первую позицию, а не в момент появления (часть элемента скрывается). Почему так и как это можно поправить?
Для наглядной демонстрации показал это на 
[примере фидла](http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/496/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    navigation: true,
    pagination: true,
    lazyLoad: true,
    autoHeight: true
  });
});
```

```css
#owl-demo .owl-item > div img {
  display: block;
  -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
  -moz-border-radius: 3px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  padding: 0px 2px
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/250x250/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=2nd Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class='lazyOwl' data-src="http://placehold.it/200x200/42bdc2/FFFFFF&text=1st Row" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный ответ - банально: `autoHeight: false`

> Add height to owl-wrapper-outer so you can use diffrent heights on slides. Use it only for one item per page setting.